# How to make infinite ScrollView with infinite amount of items in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, android-recyclerview, swiftui, uiscrollview

I'm new to IOS and SwiftUI so please correct any incorrect assumptions I make.

I need to make a View in SwiftUI that has similar functionality to `RecyclerView` in android.

Specifically what I'm trying to make is a horizontal `ScrollView` where the displayed item (the one in the centre of the screen) is constructed by its index.
for example If I'm looking at index 0 then it will display a card with some date text in ie (1st Jan 2022)
then index 1 will display 2nd jan 2022, index 2 3rd jan 2022 ect...

So you can see it could theoretically go on forever if the user wants to scroll far enough.
Because of this I can't create a list of objects and loop over them in a `HStack`. So I want some kind of functionality where I only create 3 cards and then when i scroll to the right and the index 0 card goes out of sight, it is reused as the 'new' card at the right (end) of the `ScrollView`. The same behaviour as the `RecyclerView`.

The most important thing is I need to be able to access the index for a particular rendered card, without that i can't construct my data.

Comment: `LazyHStack` is the closest implementation you will find. More advanced cell capabilities are available with UIKit with collection view and table view

Comment: Here’s a library that might be what you want: https://github.com/diegolavalledev/swiftui-series-workarounds-submission. Or if you’re just letting people pick dates, you may just want to use a DatePicker instead of something custom and complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LazyHGrid to achieve RecyclerView functionality

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    let gridItems = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: gridItems, alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(0...10, id: \.self){ number in
                    // You can create your own ReusableView and put it here
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }

}

// MARK: - PREVIEW

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: I ended up getting it working (i think) using this method so i'll mark this as correct thanks!
But i'm wondering what are the performance implications of doing: `ForEach(0...2_147_483_647, id: \.self)`?

I've tested it and it does indeed only create the visible ones, but does it create a brand new View at each index and hold onto all the previous ones? so if some wanted to scoll to index 1 million, it would hold all 1 million inner views in memory? or is clever enough to dispose of them until the user scrolls back?

Comment: LazyGrid reuse cells, Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid

Comment: Where does it say it reuses the cells? It says "creating items only as needed" but not that it reuses previous ones

Comment: @sizzlesmcnizzles Unfortunately, in my experience it doesn't reuse the cells. Using Instruments, the memory allocated will ultimately climb out of control, the more you scroll, indicating that no reuse is ever happening (and yes, there are no Leaks being detected either).

Adding to the quote from Apple's docs, "a grid that grows vertically, creating items only as needed." My experience is that as the grid grows, *then* more items are created. "Lazy" just meaning that they're created just-in-time instead of upfront.